# Не удается обратится к div, нет атрибута 'find'

Tags: python-3.x, json, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Код:

```
def get_html(url):
    print(url)
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    pl_list = soup.find('div', id='80').find('div', _class='ReactVirtualized__Grid ReactVirtualized__List')
    return pl_list

def main():
```

Ошибка:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Почему не удается обратится к контейнеру и забрать его содержимое?
Когда, как html код всей страницы возвращается, но обратится к конкретному контейнеру не могу, появляется ошибка (описана выше).
Пожалуйста помогите разобраться?

PS Это мой первый опыт написания, парсера...

Comment: /tennis/2021-02-09 возвращает html без данных, только оболочку, плюс кучу скриптов, которые загружают и показывают контент на странице... сомневаюсь, что requests хватит: там еще и сокеты... пробуйте selenium

Comment: А как же мне получить код страницы, и обратиться конкретному контейнеру?
Может попробовать обратиться через запрос на прямую к контейнеру(не знаю как точно называется) json, и попробовать забрать от туда данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По url, указанному в вопросе, вам отдают только html-оболочку, плюс кучу скриптов, которые загружают и показывают контент на странице...
Ищите в браузере через панель разработчика (chrome: F12, Network, XHR чаще всего) откуда приходят нужные данные и делайте запрос туда.

Например, для вашего случая можно найти ендпоинт api вида `/api/v1/sport/tennis/scheduled-events/`:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/sport/tennis/scheduled-events/2021-02-09'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.content)
```

Теперь у вас в `data` словарь с единственным ключом `events`, в котором список словарей, где есть данные про теннис, насколько я понимаю, за 2021-02-09:

```
for e in data['events']:
    print(f"{e['tournament']['name']}: {e['homeTeam']['name']} vs {e['awayTeam']['name']}")
```

выведет:

```
Australian Open, Melbourne, Australia: Harris L. vs Torpegaard M.
Australian Open, Melbourne, Australia: Mcdonald M. vs Cecchinato M.
Australian Open, Melbourne, Australia: Monteiro T. vs Martin A.

...

Sharm El Sheikh, Singles Qualifying M-ITF-EGY-06A: Maxted L. vs Bertola R.
Grenoble, Singles Qualifying W-ITF-FRA-02A: Niemeier J. vs Rubini S.
Grenoble, Singles Qualifying W-ITF-FRA-02A: Radwańska U. vs Desperrier G.
```

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ, буду дальше разбираться :)